AutoClicker.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details
I am trying to make an auto clicker.
I am getting this error message:

AutoClicker.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Nothing I do seems to stop it. I am new to coding so I do not really know how to solve these types of problems.
I am running this on jGRASP on Windows 10.
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class AutoClicker {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        wait(2500);
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            mouseClick();
            wait(10);
        }
    }
    public static void wait(int x) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(x);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void mouseClick() throws AWTException {
        Robot bot = new Robot();
        bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    }
}


Sorry it did not format properly, but it should have:                                                               import java.awt.*;                                                                                                                    import java.awt.event.InputEvent;                                                                                                         as well. Cheers!

So, did you compile with -Xlint:deprecation? Include the relevant details from having done that in the question.

@BasilBourque: why would we link Jgrasp to Wikipedia? Does that help anyone write a better answer? We already have a tag explaining what Jgrasp is.

@ThomasWeller Makes it convenient for anyone wondering what the heck is jGRASP. Are Wikipedia links forbidden on Stack Overflow? Did an embedded link interrupt your reading?

I am not particularly sure if I did this right, but I added -Xlint:deprecation to the top of my code, and got this error:                                                                                                    autoclicker.java:1: error: class, interface, enum, or record expected
-Xlint:deprecation
^
1 error

By the way, class names start with an uppercase letter per Java conventions.

@BasilBourque: I just feel that it does not add anything. I didn't hear of Jgrasp until just now, but I felt it was an IDE which I didn't need to know nor look up. We could also link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_clicker and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_message but we don't.

I am not particularly sure if I did this right, but I added -Xlint:deprecation to the top of my code, and got this error: autoclicker.java:1: error: class, interface, enum, or record expected -Xlint:deprecation ^ 1 error

@user27209652: Trial and error like this won't get you far. It seems you have no idea what you're doing. Sorry. Maybe watch a tutorial about Java before coding yourself, or get a mentor who programs with you. Join a local community with real people, ask your teacher, IDK.

I think it's common sense to not link everything to Wikipedia. The answers over there have no downvotes

"... I added -Xlint:deprecation to the top of my code ..."  You don't add that line to the code. You add that to the command you use to compile the code. If you are issuing the compile command from a console, it might look something like javac AutoClicker -Xlint:deprecation. If you are using an IDE, you would add it to compiler options, perhaps under Properties for the project.

Warning vs Error
You received a compiler warning, not a compiler error.
Warnings do not stop the compiler, while an error does. With just that warning, your code would compile and run.
Deprecation
Deprecation means that class, method, or constant is no longer recommended for use. See @Deprecated. That feature may even be removed eventually. So you should avoid that usage if at all possible.
Alternative
Fortunately, a suggested alternative is almost always provided along with the deprecation. That is so in your case.
java.awt.event.InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK was deprecated as of Java 9. The Javadoc says:

It is recommended that BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK and getModifiersEx() be used instead

So I suppose you should change your code to this (though I am no expert on AWT or Robot, and this code is untested):
    public static void mouseClick ( ) throws AWTException
    {
        Robot bot = new Robot( );
        bot.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK );
        bot.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK );
    }

Solving the problem
You said:

I do not really know how to solve these types of problems.

The first step always is: RTFM, Read The Fine Manual. In Java, that means reading the Javadoc documentation for the class, method, or constant. For smaller features, follow The Java™ Tutorials by Oracle, free of cost. For larger features, read the JEP (see list). Perhaps peruse the other documentation.
Second step is to search Wikipedia for technical terms like "deprecated". You will find a wealth of technical info.
